# Change placeholder text color in Magento 2 search box

Tags: magento2

Attempting to change the placeholder text color found in the search input box of Magento 2. The solution listed below worked properly for Magento 1, however I havent found any documentation on how Magento 2 handles this.

```
#search::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #0000ff; }
#search::-moz-placeholder { color: #0000ff; }
#search:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #0000ff; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a CSS change it doesn't matter if you're on Magento 1, Magento 2, or Magento 46 it should still work. I've just tested it on the Luma theme and the same code works.

```
#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to add prefixes for the other browsers to.

Answer (score 1):

AT *magento2, Search Box coming*  from `Magento_Search` module.

If want to **search box placeholder text then goto**

```
app/design/frontend/[VendorTheme]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

and  **placeholder attribute you can it text.**

If **form.mini.phtml** does exit at your theme location then just copy from ***vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates*** and paste at ***app/design/frontend/[VendorTheme]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Search/templates***

Comment: This allows the change of the text itself, what about the color? Altering the color on the class input-text does not change the color of the placerholder text.

Comment: In case anyone is trying this with the ElasticSuite module installed on the store, you must override their file instead. This file is located at **/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/view/frontend/templates/search/form.mini.phtml** and must be copied to **app/design/frontend/Gamma/DoubleR/Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/templates/search/form.mini.phtml**.

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento 2 less documentation there is a file named *css/docs/variables.html* which specifies the placeholder variables:

**Placeholder**

```
@form-element-input-placeholder__color: #c2c2c2; //Form control placeholder color
```